# jquery tabs ajax preload in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-tabs

I have implemented jquery tab in MVC. It's working fine. Now I want some customizations on it.

The code I have used

```
var total = $tabs.find('.ui-tabs-nav li').length;
var currentLoadingTab = 0;        

$tabs.bind('tabsload',function(){
    currentLoadingTab++;
    if (currentLoadingTab < total)
        $tabs.tabs('load',currentLoadingTab);
    else
        $tabs.unbind('tabsload');
}).tabs('load',currentLoadingTab);
```

But this loads all the tab content at a time.
Suppose, I have three tabs. After loading and showing the content of first tabs, the other tabs' content will be loaded in background or some kind of ajax. So that user can do normal work on first tab during loading content for others tab. When loading going on, it will show a message 'Loading...' on currently loaded tab.

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3682112/1080891) may be of help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already applied this, but the problem is that all the tabs are being loaded in sequence. We have to wait until all tabs finishes its loading. But I want the first tabs conetent should be displayed to user as soon as it completes loading and othets tab content will be loaded in background while user may work on first tab.

Comment: You could not load anything initially into the tabs. Then once they have all loaded (i.e. on document.ready() or another event of your choice, you could then make individual ajax calls, each of which would load an individual tab. Your 1st tab would be available to the user after the 'success' on the first ajax call returned.